# Can't extrude point along z axis

Tags: vertices, extrude

I am trying to extrude a point and I can't move it on the Z axis. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Hello, hard to tell, could you please show some screenshot or animated gif?

Comment: Hi @moonboots, I just updated to include my project file

Comment: @moonboots I get the same problem with a new project file. I create a point from the Curve menu, then when I extrude a second point, it can't move on the Z axis

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch your curve from 2D to 3D:

[image]

Comment: I like those pointing fingers, they are hard to miss.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Gorgeous, aren't they? :)